# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'leave') || Disocrd.JS V.14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is my code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, StringSelectMenuBuilder, ButtonBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('servers')
        .setDescription('Displays a dropdown menu with all the servers the bot is in.'),
        async execute(interaction) {

        if (interaction.user.id !== '759753313553743893') {
            return interaction.reply({ content: 'You are not authorized to use this command!', ephemeral: true });
        }

        // Fetch all the guilds the bot is in
        const guilds = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch();

        // Create an object with guild IDs as properties and guild names as values
        const guildList = {};
        guilds.forEach(guild => {
            guildList[guild.id] = guild.name;
        });

        // Create the options for the select menu
        const serverOptions = Object.keys(guildList).map(guildID => ({ label: guildList[guildID], value: guildID }));

        // Create the select menu
        const serverMenu = new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
            .setCustomId('server_menu')
            .setPlaceholder('Select a server')
            .addOptions(serverOptions);

        // Create the initial embed message with the select menu
        const initialEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Server List')
            .setDescription('Please select a server from the dropdown menu.')
            .setColor('#00ff00')
            .setFooter({ text: 'Server Management System' })
            .setTimestamp();

        const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(serverMenu);

        const initialMessage = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [initialEmbed], components: [row], fetchReply: true, ephemeral: true });

        // Create the button that will kick the bot from the selected server
        const kickButton = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('kick_button')
            .setLabel('Kick bot')
            .setStyle('Danger');

        // Listen for the select menu to be interacted with
        const filter = (interaction) => {
            return interaction.customId === 'server_menu';
        };
        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });

        collector.on('collect', async (interaction) => {
            // Get the selected server ID and guild object
            const selectedServer = interaction.values[0];
            const guild = interaction.client.guilds.cache.get(selectedServer);

            // Edit the embed message with the selected server's name and the kick button
            const updatedEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle(guild.name)
                .setDescription('Do you want to kick the bot from this server?')
                .setColor('#ff0000')
                .setFooter({ text: 'Server Management System' })
                .setTimestamp();

            const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(kickButton);

            await interaction.update({ embeds: [updatedEmbed], components: [row], ephemeral: true });
        });

        // Listen for the kick button to be interacted with
        const buttonFilter = (interaction) => {
            return interaction.customId === 'kick_button';
        };
        const buttonCollector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ buttonFilter, time: 15000 });

        buttonCollector.on('collect', async (interaction) => {
            // Get the selected server ID and guild object
            const selectedServer = interaction.message.embeds[0].title;
            const guildID = Object.keys(guildList).find(id => guildList[id] === selectedServer);
            const guild = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch(guildID);
            if (guild) {
                // Leave the guild
                await guild.leave();
            
                // Reply to the interaction with a success message
                await interaction.update({ content: `The bot has been kicked from ${selectedServer}.`, embeds: [], components: [], ephemeral: true });
            } else {
                // If the guild is not found, reply to the interaction with an error message
                await interaction.update({ content: `Could not find ${selectedServer}.`, embeds: [], components: [], ephemeral: true });
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This is a command that has a dropdown with all the server the bot is joined in. When I select a specific server it asks me if I want to kick it form the server. But when I click the button "Kick" it return my this error at the terminal:

```
C:\Users\kalam\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\Botanser\Commands\Moderation\servers.js:76
            await guild.leave();
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'leave')
```

### My intents:

-> `const { Guilds, GuildMembers, GuildMessages, MessageContent, DirectMessages, GuildVoiceStates } = GatewayIntentBits;`

->  `intents: [Guilds, GuildMembers, GuildMessages, MessageContent, DirectMessages, GuildVoiceStates]`

Any answer will be accepted. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are running into issues, is due to the fact that `guild` is undefined. Specifically on the following line:

```js
const guild = interaction.client.guilds.cache.find(guild => guild.name === selectedServer);
```

It might be in your better interest to use the `client.guilds.fetch()` method, which would guarantee it's existence. *(As long as the client is still in the server.)*

Here is an example:

```js
const guild = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch(<guild_id>)
if (guild) {
    // whatever ...
}
```

I suggest not storing values that may be needed later in an embed. It would be more beneficial (and in most cases, more practical) to use an object, with all the currently available guilds to select from as properties. IDs are the better way to go when it comes to storing information about guilds, as IDs are unique and not the same as any other guild.

#### Documentation Links

Fetch: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=fetch

Comment: This answer does not solve my case. Do you have to suggest anything better?